# Tesseract OCR Giving inaccurate results

Tags: android, ocr

I have implemented an android application for OCR using [Android OCR Sample](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)

But it is giving inaccurate results.
Can anyone suggest me how can i resolve this or do we have any other OCR libraries which are giving accurate and fast results ?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/40504023/1012284

Comment: Your question isn't detailed enough. You didn't say what you're trying to do with your app (scan receipts? scan license plates?), and you didn't give examples of input images.

Comment: I have tried with document scan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/is-there-any-free-ocr-library-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

I am searching OCR library but i found paid OCR library

Adobe Acrobat Pro ( RTF file format gives you best result )

Captiva

Abbyy

Informatica ( Not sure which module within Informatica )

IBM Datacapture (Datacap) (IBM Watson)